# Java display calendar-like data

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I am working on java and i want to make my java GUI display data like this.
What component or what layout should i use?

First, i think i should do something with JTable to display the table like this.

Second, in each day in this calendar it is clickable. and I think I'll use JButton.I'm not sure if it's ok.

third, the most top of the calendar, i have no idea how to make it display like that.

[image: I want my java GUI display as this one]

Comment: `JTable` would be a good choice, you could use a `GridBagLayout` instead, allowing each cell to be a component of it's own...

Comment: @MadProgrammer do you have any tutorial site for GridbagLayout?

Comment: [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)